# how to solve this question of polynomial

Tags: polynomials

> if $(x-3)$ and $x-1/3$ are both the factors of polynomial
>   $f(x)=ax^2+5x+b$, then
>    (a) $a=5b$, (b) $a=b$, (c) $a=3, b=2$, (d)
>   $a=+-b$

to solve this question i kept $x-3$ equal to $0$ and also kept $x-1/3$ equals to $0$ and then finded the value of $x=$ 3 and 1/3 and then put these values in the equations at one at a time  and then i got two equations and then i put those two equation equals to each other. the answer obtained was $a =-3/8$ which is absolutely wrong and its answer is (b) $a=b$.

help me to solve this question....thanks

Comment: $f(x) = a(x-3)(x-1/3)$

Answer (score 2):

By the hypothesis
$$f(x)=a(x-3)\left(x-\frac13\right)$$
so we see easily that 
$$b=a\times(-3)\times\left(-\frac13\right)=a$$

Answer (score 1):

As you note, $f(3) = f(1/3) = 0$, so
$$
9a+15+b = 0
$$
and
$$
\frac{a}{9} + \frac{5}{3} + b = 0 \Rightarrow a+15+9b = 0
$$
Subtracting these two equations, you get
$$
8a-8b = 0 \Rightarrow a=b
$$

Comment: i got my mistake i didn't multiplied 9 by $0$ in equation 2nd... thanks